# Unit Testing: How to mock class variable in Dart?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

can I get some suggestions on how can I mock `_appointmentCollection` variable in my `AppointmentService` class from below please ?

Here is my Service

```
class AppointmentService {
  CollectionReference _appointmentCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('appointments');

  Future<bool> scheduleAppointment(
    Appointment appointment,
    String useremail,
  ) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> appointmentInfo = appointment.toJson();
    try {
      await _appointmentCollection.doc(useremail).update({
        "appointments": FieldValue.arrayUnion([appointmentInfo]),
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I generated mocks for my class using flutter command `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Now inside my test class I am trying to mock interaction of `_appointmentCollection.doc().....` with something like this
`when(mockAppointmentCollection.doc(any())).thenDoNothing()....`
but I am having hard time finding documentation related to how can I mock class variable in Dart.

Here is my test class I have at the moment

```
@GenerateMocks([AppointmentService])
void main() {
  group("Test Appointment Service", () {
    test("schedule appointment should return true or false", () {
      final appointmentService = MockAppointmentService();
      // TODO: create mock of appointmentCollection variable
      expect(2, 2);
      // Above assertion is dummy one just to make sure I can run tests
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: A member variable is just a getter and setter, and the [mockito README](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) shows examples for stubbing getters and setters. However, `AppointmentService._appointmentCollection` isn't public, so that wouldn't be useful for a `MockAppointmentService` anyway.  If instead you want `MockAppointmentService` to *use* `mockAppointmentCollection`, then you would need to modify your class so that tests can supply the `CollectionReference` object to use (that pattern typically goes by the name "dependency injection", although I personally hate that name).

Comment: @jamesdlin This is the area I am struggling in my app. I am able to split code into widgets, controllers and services, but while testing service like above AppointmentService, I am struggling in Dependency management. I really don't want to pass values in constructor, which gets too clumsy I feel. Do you have any suggestions for me which dependency management package I can use and can write unit tests with ?

Comment: I'm not personally a fan of most "dependency injection" frameworks.  I don't see what's clumsy about passing a value in the constructor; a typical pattern would be to make the constructor argument optional, and then existing callers would be unaffected.  Alternatively you could add a setter to your class used only by tests (optionally with the [`@visibleForTesting` attribute](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/visibleForTesting-constant.html)).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you so much. It helped a lot. I would like to use some more of your knowledge in understanding how this mocks work. I am still bit confused about how can I mock firestore calls. For example, I have a function that calls `.doc(...).update(...)`. Here is the gist for that https://gist.github.com/SatyaAchanta/b1bfc8505f96d417af19966cd06ded53

What I am trying to do is, I want to fail `.doc(..).update(...)` call so that I fall in catch block and can assert false in response. TBH, I am not expecting to see answer from you, but if you can help me understand, I can give a shot.

Comment: @jamesdlin Alright, I believe I got tests working as expected. For success case, I didn't need any mocking. Since I am calling Mock collections, I let `collection.doc(..).update(..)` call go through, but to test failure case, I have to create Mock of CollectionReference and raise exception when calling `collection.doc(..)`, which eventually falls in catch block as per my previous discussion. Here is the working gist
[Unit Test Firestore](https://gist.github.com/SatyaAchanta/f81790e022621629030069ca55d66973)